# Android SignalR does not make connection with Samsung Devices

Tags: android, asp.net, signalr, samsung-mobile, signalr.client

I have an App which uses SignalR and do some working. It works on all of the other devices but whenever i run the app on Samsung Devices. It never make an connection. Is there any configuration which i need to turn on in the Samsung? or i have to do some alternate path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had found this strange problem occurred while connecting SignalR with Samsung Galaxy III Devices. while Other samsung mobile connect the app. and Found the solution in Microsoft MVP Shai Raiten's Blog.

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2013/05/14/signalr-isnt-working-on-samsung-galaxy-3/

follow the steps given in the second link of the blog address given step by step to solve this problem.